# Localizing content of Text containing images and text

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUI Text is capable of displaying text inline with images via "+" operator or string interpolation

```
(Text("Hello, ") + Text(Image(systemName: "globe")) + Text("!")).font(.title)
```

or

```
Text("Hello, \(Image(systemName: "globe")) !").font(.title)
```

[image]

Has anyone ever tried to to localize something like this?

Answer (score 0):

By calling `Text("Hello, ")` you're using this initialiser:

```
public init(_ key: LocalizedStringKey, tableName: String? = nil, bundle: Bundle? = nil, comment: StaticString? = nil)
```

Which means that SwiftUI will try to localise the `"Hello, "` string (which might not be what you expect).

I'd recommend splitting up text which needs to be localised and other characters/symbols/images:

```
// Localised part + non-localised part
Text("Hello") + Text(", \(Image(systemName: "globe"))!")
```

Now you can localise just the `"Hello"` string and it should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your response but hardcoding the order of localized content parts might cause localization problems. Consider a language where "Hello world!" is actually "World hello!". As you can see `Text(localizedHello) + Text(Image(systemName: "globe"))` logic fails in this case